# Why 瞋 displayed different than its components sometimes

Tags: characters

The description says it's 目 + 真
But in places the same unicode rendered the character next to 目 into nothing like 真.
The other form is like the drawing in this screenshot. Anyone knows why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9C%9F):

> The Kangxi dictionary considers 真 as an unorthodox form (俗字) of 眞. However, the traditional Kangxi form 眞 with 匕 on top is rarely used nowadays. In modern times, 真 is considered the orthodox form in all regions except South Korea.

眞 is the original, proper form of the character.

Comment: "眞 is the original, proper form of the character."—well, no. When you look at historical calligraphy (http://www.sfds.cn/771F/ http://www.sfds.cn/771E/) you will find that 真 has been used for millennia by figures no less than 顏真卿 and 王羲之. 眞 is an attempt to partly adapt the character shape to the form that is shown, in small seal, in the 说文解字 (100CE); as such, it is rather a hypercorrect than 'the proper' form.